# excel if function with date

Tags: excel, function, date, if-statement

I have two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

#### Sheet1

```
A   B      C     H
C-1 Hall-1 ok    30-04-2018
c-2 Hall-2 ok
c-3 Hall-3 ok
```

#### Sheet2

```
A           B      C
29-04-2018 Hall-1 ok
29-04-2018 Hall-2 ok
29-04-2018 Hall-3 ok
30-04-2018 Hall-1 ok
30-04-2018 Hall-2 ok
30-04-2018 Hall-3 ok
01-05-2018 Hall-1 ok
01-05-2018 Hall-2 ok
01-05-2018 Hall-3 ok
```

Sheet1 H1 cell value will change on daily basis. I tried the following formula:

```
=IF($H$1=Sheet2!$B$4:$B$500,(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$B7,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$500,2,FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know exactly what you are asking without seeing the sheet properly. The reason is that the VLOOKUP function is quite specific.

However I think the problem is that VLOOKUP only looks up your value in the first column of the table that you give it.

For example:

```
 A               B                C                 D
 Date            Stuff            More              MoreStuff
 Date            Stuff            More              MoreStuff
 Date            Stuff            More              MoreStuff
 Date            Stuff            More              MoreStuff
```

If I have value: X and I want to get value: Y from my table which is in column C:

I need to use the formula as follows:

```
 =VLOOKUP(X, A:D, 3, False)
```

So VLOOKUP will look up your date ONLY in the first column. If your data is in column B and you put A:D then it won't find it. It will find it if you put B:D.

1) **Basically: check that your column of dates in the lookup table is the left most column in the table that you give it.**

Finally:

2) The number in the third argument of the VLOOKUP function must be counted from the start of your new table, not the worksheet.

```
 A     B     C      D        E
 stuff stuff Date   Stuff    Result     
 stuff stuff Date   Stuff    Result
```

If that is your table, and I want the result from column E using the date in column C I would need to use VLOOKUP as follows:

```
 VLOOKUP(X C:E, 3, False)
```

I think in your case, your sheet is like this:

```
 A        B         C
 Date     Entry     Entry2
```

To get Entry 2 you would do

```
 VLOOKUP(x, A:C, 3, False)
```

Comment: Hi Lgjmac, Please find the attachment of my excel workbook for your reference, my requirement is, i am choosing date in sheet1, remaining data's(fields) automatically to be fill in sheet1(data's available in sheets2).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Array formula in cell `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$C$9,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$9=$H$1,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$9),""),ROW(1:1)),COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)),"")
```

The Array formula needs to be added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering it in the cell. Adjust the ranges to match your own.

Screenshot:

[image]

Again, you *must* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after putting the formula in the cell.